# is $p \land (p \lor q)$ a tautology?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I would just like to know whether my work is correct before I continue on with the rest of the questions.

$$p \land (p \lor q)$$

$$p \land (\lnot p \rightarrow q)$$

$$(p \land \lnot p) \rightarrow q$$

$$F \rightarrow q$$

with this, I'm going to say it is not a tautology.

Comment: Try using the tableau method in future :)

Comment: The third formula does not follow from the second. At the end of the day, $p\land(p\lor q)\equiv p$.

Comment: In addition to what triple_sec says, you should know that $F\rightarrow q$ *is* a tautology, because it is true regardless of the value of $q$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not a tautology.

$p \land (p\lor q)$ it is not true when both $p$ and $q$ are false. A tautology is a proposition that is always true, no matter what the truth-values of its variables.

Note that the following equivalence does **not** hold: $$p\land(\lnot p \lor q) \equiv (p \land \lnot p) \lor q\tag{wrong}$$

Associativity only works when the connectives are both $\land,$ or both $\lor$.

What we do have is $$p\land(\lnot p \lor q) \equiv (p\land \lnot p) \lor (p \land q)\equiv F \lor (p \land q)\equiv p \lor q$$

Comment: You live for these ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Not a tautology]

If you use truth tables u will find that its not a tautology.
Please refer the attachment